# Unity C# global namespace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im having problems with global name spaces in Unity With C#

I have the following code in two separate files

```
FILE: MyUtil.cs

using ....
using ....

public class MyUtil :  Photon.PunBehaviour
{
  public static IEnumerator DoStuff(string link)
  {
      WWW sss=new WWW(link);
      yield return sss;
  }
}



FILE: TestClass.cs

using ....
using ....

namespace NewNameSpace {
  public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour
  {
     public void useIt()
     {
       StartCoroutine(global::MyUtil.DoStuff("www.link.com")); <<< error here
     }
  }
}
```

Im getting error on the `StartCoroutine` line saying that `MyUtil` class itself is not found in the global namespace.

I want to call MyUtil.DoStuff from useIt method, but it wont compile.

Anybody knows why?

Thanks

Comment: It should just work without the `global::`, have you tried?

Comment: Yes i tried it without the global::, and also tried "global." but no work either :(

Comment: Do you have `util.cs` in your assets folder or is it a file on your hard drive? Can you edit your question with a screenshot of the assets folder with these two files?

Comment: Actually i typed the name wrong in here, its actually MyUtil.cs, not util.cs, sorry about that. But it still doesnt work!

Comment: Why not update your question and fix it? Also put **complete** of what both scripts looks like. This will help people replicate your problem.

Comment: I updated it, the actual script is really long, but what i have shown is what is actually happening. I dont know if because the namespace is different, and one class is static???

Comment: There is somthing else you are doing wrong that you are not showing us. I have VERY similar code running in a project and it works fine just doing `StartCoroutine(MyUtil.DoStuff("www.link.com"));` Also, if `MyUtil` is only going to have static methods you should declare it as `public static class MyUtil { ... }` instead.

Comment: I call methds from MyUtil in many other classes all over the place with no problems, its just this one time im getting this problem from this one class, i dont know why! Im stuck!!!! Dont know what to do!

Comment: I tried making MyUtil public static (public static class MyUtil : Photon.PunBehaviour) then it gave another error that static classes can only be derived from Object;

Comment: Why is MyUtil deriving from `Photon.PunBehaviour` at all? Are you using functions from that class?

Comment: Its doing simple checks in there to determine if its MasterClient, but nothing other than that, just simple stuff, this is really bazzar because Im calling lots of functions in MyUtil in many other classes, but seems i cant call it from this class, maybe because this class in a different namespace? says MyUtil doesnt exist in current context??

Comment: I even removed the namespace line but it STILL doesnt work!

Comment: Very strange, seems I can access no other classes whose file is not in the same folder in unity. So MyUtil cant be accessed and no other class in the whole project can be accessed either if its not in the same folder as TestClass.cs

Comment: What happens if you replaced `Photon.PunBehaviour` with `MonoBehaviour` ? The error is still there?

Answer (score 2):

Scripts in the Plugins folder cant see scripts in other folders, but scripts in other folders can see scripts in Plug in.

The script that was giving me problems was located in the Plugsins folder.

This is what caused the problem, so I moved the scripts from plugins to another folder and everything worked.

Thanks everybody for your comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

`MyUtil` is a `MonoBehaviour`, and as far as I know, the name of that component needs to match with the file name. If not, Unity won't compile it.

That is why compiler cannot find it.

To fix this, change the name of util.cs to MyUtil.cs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, actually the file is already MyUtil.cs (I typed it wrong in here)